# Facebook C# Application Remembering Email after logout

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, sdk, logout

I'm working on a public kiosk that will allow users to publish a post to Facebook.  Everything seems to be working fine for the most part, but the one issue I've been unable to solve is that it seems to be remembering the email address used to log-in previously.  The previous user is logged out, but it just automatically populates the email field on the Facebook Log-in screen.

I'm using C# and a WPF WebControl, I've tried adjusting the browser security settings on the machine to deactivate AutoComplete, but it still fills that field.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to combat this?

Comment: clear your cookies/history? what's the WebControl?